# Canonical way to test data types

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Typeable(typeOf)

myFunc :: (Show a) => [a] -> [String]
myFunc
  | show (typeOf a) == "[Char]" = ...
  | otherwise = ..
```

I use the above code to test if the input is of the `String` type.
Is this correct and acceptable or are there other better ways?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this idiomatic, but it might depend on your context. This could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Which problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkSeemann My problem is trivial: If input is not of String type, I would use show. otherwise I just use the string itself.

Comment: @daydaynatation: Usually, when I’ve heard people ask how to do that, it’s because they’re using `Show` for pretty-printing/human-readable output. `Show` and `Read` are meant for debugging, and should almost always just be derived. That’s why `show` produces a string containing *Haskell code* (e.g. with quotes & escapes for strings) instead of nicely formatted text. I like [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) and its `pretty` function for this purpose. It does what you want in this case: `instance Pretty String` just formats the contents directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like with matching values, we prefer to avoid using booleans altogether. In context of typeable/dynamic, this means you shouldn't “test” whether it is some particular type and then do something *if* it is, but instead (like with value pattern-matching) you simply *try* to use it as that type, and then add fallback cases just for when that fails.

```
myFunc' :: (Show a, Typeable a) => a -> String
myFunc' x = case cast x of
       Just xStr -> xStr
       _ -> show x
```

Note that I don't even need to mention that `xStr` handles the case where `x` is `String`, because that is already implied by the context.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen somebody put the documentation link in-line in the code like that before. Nice trick! I'll be stealing that if you don't mind.